# HTML5 text control with read-only and editable parts

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to obtain a text input visual element that to look unitary but to have two parts arranged horizontally, with different behaviors. The one from the left would have to be read only, while the one from the left should be editable.

Any suggestion about how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just place two inputs next to each other and style them appropriately. Example jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xvKCH/1/.

```
<input type='text' readonly class='readonly'></input><input type='text' class='writable'></input>​

input {
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;      
}

.readonly {
    border-right: 0;
}

.writable {
    border-left: 0;
}​
```

Comment: If you put a newline after the first input, Chrome will render it as a space between the two inputs, breaking the illusion of a single control.  You can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/QmpXM/.